# Wrap code in a datarow function

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have the following code which assigns values to a datarow and and adds to the datatable. I want to write function which returns a datarow which enables me to write less code. Please check the code below and provide me any suggestions

```
            objRow = dtTODO.NewRow
            objRow.Item("Item") = "Test"
            objRow.Item("Message") = "Test"
            objRow.Item("ButtonText") = "Add"
            dtTODO.Rows.Add(objRow)

            objRow = dtTODO.NewRow
            objRow.Item("Item") = "Test2"
            objRow.Item("Message") = "Test2"
            objRow.Item("ButtonText") = "Add"
            dtTODO.Rows.Add(objRow)
```

Assume that I am adding the above records. I want to create a function which returns a datarow as,

```
Public Function ItemRow(ByVal strItem As String, ByVal strMessage As String, ByVal strButtonText As String, ByVal strUrl As String) As DataRow

End Function
```

And add this as,

dtTODO.Rows.Add(ItemRow(item, msg,bttext,url))

Hope I am not confusing too much :).

Comment: You pretty much already have your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You function signature seems ok only You have to pass the dtTODO.Newrow reference to the function as well.

Try this:

```
AddRow("a", "b", "c", dtTODO);
AddRow("a", "b", "c", dtTODO);

void AddRow(string str1, string str2, string str3, DataTable dt)
{
        DataRow objRow = dtTODO.NewRow();
        objRow["Item"] = str1;
        objRow["Message"] = str2;
        objRow["ButtonText"] = str3;
        dt.Rows.Add(objRow);
}
```

You can get much better code as well.

Please convert the above code to VB

Comment: Can you explain me more by putting a sample.